# jQuery Mobile - multi-language mobile web application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, multilingual

What can be a solution to add a multiple language support into a web mobile application which works also offline? I have red some articles like [this](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-translator-plugins/). I'm looking for something like a plugin, i don't want to lose much time to build a dictionary (I hope). Can you give me some advices?

Comment: You won't get a translation plugin that works offline unless you also have local copies of very large dictionaries - one for each language.  You should look at a simple string resource type scenario where you load a different script for each language, and they define label text as variables, so each language can have a different value but the core application doesn't change.

Comment: use [i18next](http://jamuhl.github.io/i18next/), which works nicely with JQM and allows to store dicts in localstorage, so they would be available offline. However the dict you have to write yourself :-)

Answer (score 2):

html5 which used in jquery mobile which provide local storage store data local and get data, you can use as globally.I have done my app using phone gap and jquery mobile in english and arbic, no need to use any plugin. You can use offline or online.

```
 localStorage.setItem("key", value);
 localStorage.getItem(key);
```